# Connecting QPushButton's sizes

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a grid-like view with QPushButtons. The buttons content isn't static, so the column sizes expands dynamically. And I want same column size for each column for aesthetical reasons.

Now I'm using an adjust_sizes function after showing the widget, because I noticed If I call it before showing the widget, nothing changes. But my solutions seems ugly to me. Is there a better way for that?

My function:

```
def adjust_sizes(self):
    max_width=0
    for i in self.buttons:
        if i.geometry().width() > max_width : 
            max_width=i.geometry().width()
    for i in self.buttons: i.setMinimumSize(max_width,0)
```

And thats how I use it:

```
g=launcher()
g.show()
g.adjust_sizes()
```

Is there a better way for doing that?

**Edit:**
As for clarify here is the desired screenshots(Look at Raceyman's answer):

Desired Look:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ9wO.png]

Here is what I get:

[image]

My System:

Arch Linux x86_64, Python 3.2 or 2.7.1, PyQt 4.8.4, Qt 4.7.3

Comment: what layout class are you using?

Comment: sorry, I thought that one had something to always have all the columns with the same width, but that's not the case. You could make your code just a tiny bit better by setting the grid's `setColumnMinimumWidth` rather than each button's, but that's not much of a gain.

Comment: @Mat, but the layout didn't defined with "self.", so I prefer not to edit so much code for that (I'm not using designer).

Answer (score 1):

My apologies if this isn't really an answer (it's a bit long for comments), but I'm wondering if the version of PyQt you're using might be part of the cause.  I'm using 4.8.3 (I think), and when I build a dialog this way using QGridLayout the columns, by default, are all equal sizes.  Here is a (very, very, very crude) example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class launcher(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        mainlayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        buttons = [['a', 'aaaa', 'aaaaaaa', 'a'], 
                   ['b', 'bbbbbbbbbb', 'bbbbb', 'b'], 
                   ['c','c','c', 'c']]
        for i, buttonrow in enumerate(buttons):
            for j, button in enumerate(buttonrow):                
                mainlayout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton(button), i, j)
        self.setLayout(mainlayout)
        self.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    g = launcher()
    g.show()
```

Here is a screenshot of the resultant dialog:

[image]

Hopefully this is similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do, but when I run your example code on my system, its the result: http://tiny.cc/s9b1a .

My system:

Arch Linux x86_64,
Python 3.2 or 2.7.1,
PyQt 4.8.4,
Qt 4.7.3,
Using Oxygen Widget Set.

Comment: Ah.  I'm using Windows, so that must be one fundamental difference between Qt on our platforms.  I think you may not have any other choice that determining the maximum button width then setting either all of the horizontal button sizes, or column widths to that value.  Sorry I couldn't help.